# SQL query with OR condition on 2 joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I have a `projects` table, a `users` table, a `write_permissions` table and a `read_permissions` table. Both `read_permissions` and `write_permissions` have 2 columns: `project_id` and `user_id` (this is a purposely contrived example, I'm not looking for alternative table settings).

I need for a given user to find all the projects on which he has a write permission or a read permission.

For instance for a user with write permissions on projects A and B, and read permission only on project C, and no permissions for project D, I need to write a query that returns the projects A, B and C.

The query may need to take additional JOIN clauses. For instance I may have a `categories` table, and a `projects_categories` table with columns `projects_id` and `user_id`, and may want to find all the projects on which a user has write permission and read permission, and that belongs to a given category.

Comment: you want us to write the query for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM  (
   SELECT project_id
   FROM   write_permissions
   WHERE  user_id = 1
   UNION
   SELECT project_id
   FROM   read_permissions 
   WHERE  user_id = 1
   ) sub
JOIN projects p USING (project_id);
```

`UNION` without `ALL` automatically folds duplicates in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [project_id] FROM [read_permissions] WHERE [user_id]=@user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT [project_id] FROM [write_permissions] WHERE [user_id]=@user_id
```

this will give you the project that user have read or write premission on them
now you can use it's result

Comment: `[project_id]` is an invalid identifier in SQL (and in Postgres)

Comment: project_id is field name, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, `project_id` is correct, but `[project_id]` is not (at least not in Postgres and standard SQL)

Comment: you're right,but in TSql it's correct.I checked it for table name and field names

Comment: But the question is tagged with `postgresql` and `sql` (which is the tag for "standard sql"). It is neither tagged `tsql` nor `sql-server`